# Perl -- read filenames with specific extensions

Tags: perl, file

Need to read two files with specific extensions using `wildcards`. I need something like this:

Open folder and read files

```
if file1 is ending with .xml
then $xmlfile = "fileName.xml"

if file2 is ending with .txt
then $txtfile = "fileName.txt"
```

Filenames always include some non_constat_data in the file name. But they always will start with constat string and end with extension `.xml` or `.txt`.

Comment: You're welcome! What is your question?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you are expecting to get a viable answer to your question.

Comment: You need to give us a bit more information. For example, how do you know the file names? Will you be given `foo`, and then need to read `foo.txt` and `foo.xml`? Or, in some random directory, you'll have a file `foo.xml` and `foo.txt`, and only these two files will have these endings?  Or, will there be a lot of files with the `.xml` and `.txt` suffixes, and you need to find the only ones with the same prefix? And, we haven't even gotten to how to read the files. Processing XML can be tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you right then you want to do something like this.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

opendir my $dir, "/path/to/folder" or die "Can't open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir $dir;
closedir $dir;

foreach my $file (@files)
{
    if ($file =~ m/\.xml$/)
    {
        my $xmlfile = $file;
        print "$xmlfile\n";
    }
    elsif ($file =~ m/\.txt$/)
    {
        my $txtfile = $file;
        print "$txtfile\n";
    }
}
```

This open the folder and look for file extension and assign the file to a variable.

Note : This is not reading file contents.

Comment: This is probably what I need. However, it's about 7 years last time I code with PERL, and I can't remember how to do this.

Comment: @Jussi : If this helped you, you can accept this as an answer.

Comment: This seem the right thing. Put I have added two lines in the end of this exsample:

print "$xmlfile\n";
print "$txtfile\n";

And this gives an errror:

Global symbol "$xmlfile" requires explicit package name at ./GnuPG_check.pl line 27.
Global symbol "$txtfile" requires explicit package name at ./GnuPG_check.pl line 28.

??

Comment: Yep, this works, but I need to use $xmlfile and $txtfile out of the loop ?

Comment: Just declare both variable `$xmlfile` and `$txtfile` out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the function like this

```
sub first_file_of_the_type {
    my $ext = shift =~ s/.*\.//r;
    +(<*.$ext>)[0];
}
```

And then use it in this way

```
my $xmlfile = first_file_of_the_type("fileName.xml");
my $txtfile = first_file_of_the_type("fileName.txt");
```